# Discord Bot - Java script code to Python

Tags: javascript, python, discord

Okay, so my java script bot has a line of code that i am trying to recreate in python!  If anyone could tell me the pieces i would need to make it.  Or even how to make it in python i would **greatly** appreciate it!

```
const fs = require("fs");
let points = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./points.json", "utf8"));

client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return; // always ignore bots!

  // if the points don"t exist, init to 0;
  if (!points[message.author.id]) points[message.author.id] = {
    points: 0,
    level: 0
  };
  points[message.author.id].points++;

  // And then, we save the edited file.
  fs.writeFile("./points.json", JSON.stringify(points), (err) => {
    if (err) console.error(err)
  });
});
```

I want to keep using .json if possible!  But if theirs a better way please tell! <3

Comment: I should also explain its a leveling system for messages sent, but i don't know how to export and import files using python.  So this is basically what i'm wanting!

Comment: I'm pretty sure all the answers you need could be found with a series of Googles.

Answer (score 0):

For python 2, files can be opened with `open`. Use the `r` or `w` flag depending if you want to read or write. For example:

```python
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line)
```

```python
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('my output')
```

For json, use the built-in library https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

This snippet shows writing a json object to a file

```python
import json

# store data in a dictionary
obj = {'name': 'joe'}

# write object to an output file
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(obj, f)
```